# ASP.NET On Response.Write to iframe complete

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I'm developing an application in ASP.NET that is designed to create reports and download them to the client. I'm doing this using an iframe that is posted to the server. Once operations are completed, the report is downloaded to the client using Response.Write().

In the meantime, on the client, I am displaying a GIF to indicate that the server is generating the report. When the report is successfully created and has finished writing to the client, I would like to update the iframe accordingly, and hide the GIF.

Is there any way of determining if the response.write() was successful in the iframe's parent page?

Parent:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="import-upload.html" width="100%" height="300" onload="loadFrame()" frameborder="0">

function redirect(type) {
        iframe.getElementById('inputType').value = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
        iframe.getElementById('inputAction').value = type;

        document.getElementById("divOptionsContainer").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("imgLoadingGif").style.display = "";

        iframe.getElementById('frmUpload').submit();
    }
```

Iframe Source:

```
<div align="center">
    <form id="frmUpload" action="AjaxFileHandler.aspx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_self" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" />
        <input type="hidden" id="inputAction" name="action"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="inputType" name="type"/>
    </form>

    <button id="btnReport" type="button" onclick="parent.redirect('Report')" style="">Report</button>
    <button id="btnUpload" type="button" onclick="parent.redirect('Import')" style="">Import</button>
</div>
```

This is my first post. Please let me know if more information is needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `onload` event of iframe:

```
function redirect(type) {
    iframe.getElementById('inputType').value = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
    iframe.getElementById('inputAction').value = type;

    document.getElementById("divOptionsContainer").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("imgLoadingGif").style.display = "";

    iframe.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("divOptionsContainer").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("imgLoadingGif").style.display = "none";
    }

    iframe.getElementById('frmUpload').submit();
}
```

Comment: That works well for a redirect, but it doesn't seem to work for a response.write().

Comment: Can you post the responses headers from the POST request? You can copy them from the network tab of Chrome development tool.